# Dropbox file type icons

Tags: iphone

Hello i am making an iphone app using the dropbox sdk and i want to know how to use the same icons that they use for file types? I notice these are the same icons used on the mac. Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [Dropbox Developer's page](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/docs) contains a link to a [zipfile](https://www.dropbox.com/static/images/dropbox-api-icons.zip) with all these icons. The `DBMetadata` object contains an `icon` property that will tell you which icon to use for each file.

Comment: The only bad thing about these icons is that they are sized 16x16 and 48x48; so they aren't ready to be used for people programming for both retina and non-retina devices.

Answer (score 1):

This site explains how you can get a psd of mac icons:
http://creativebits.org/mac_os_x/get_a_psd_of_your_application_icons